# Mysql count how many queries per second are executed, is there any way?

Tags: mysql, performance, lamp, metrics

i have a busy web server with LAMP installed, and i was wondering, is there any way to count how many queries per second (mysql) are executed in the server ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT s1.variable_value / s2.variable_value
FROM information_schema.global_status s1, information_schema.global_status s2
WHERE s1.variable_name='queries'
AND s2.variable_name ='uptime';
```

Comment: For anyone using mysql 5.7+, the global status table has moved to the performance_schema

Answer (score 8):

Try Jeremy Zawodny's excellent utility [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/).

If you have the Perl module [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-HiRes/) installed, mytop will automatically use it to generate high-resoution query per second information.

Comment: i don't have that installed. i found some other way 

mysqladmin status

Answer (score 5):

There's useful information to be mined from the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; command, including the number of queries executed (if your MySQL is 5.0.76 or later).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html

Comment: what all the questions included as part of this queries...?

Comment: I am serching for how mysql calculates this questions values or queries values. I am doing the sum of COM_SELECT, COM_UPDATE, COM_SET_OPTION, COM_UPDATE, COM_DELETE and few more but not getting the exact match between these two.

Comment: The diff between `Questions` and `Queries` may involve Stored Routines.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p  status
```

which will return output like:

```
Uptime: 17134  Threads: 2  Questions: 1245  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 49  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 42  Queries per second avg: 0.072
```

Here queries per second is:  **0.072**, which is `questions/uptime`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the "STATUS" command (not SHOW STATUS), MySQL will calculate the queries per second since server start for you.

Tested with MySQL 5.1.63.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a small script for this. It will be some thing like the below.

```
    declare -i a
    declare -i b
    declare -i c
    a=`mysql -uroot -pxxxxx -e "show status like 'Queries'" | 
    tail -1 | awk '{print    $2}'`
    echo "$a"
    sleep 1
    b=`mysql -uroot -pxxxxx -e "show status like 'Queries'" | 
    tail -1 | awk '{print                 $2}'`
    echo "$b"
    c=$b-$a
    echo "Number of Queries per second is: $c"
```

Comment: This should be all possible to do within MySQL wouldn't it? I don't know how to do it sadly.